# Find a dictionary that meets certain criteria and return a value from it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary containing a list of dictionaries. The number of dictionaries in the list could be infinite or could be 0 (not present at all), and the keys for these dictionaries will typically be identical, but with differing values. In the dict below, how best could I access the dict that contains "type : web" and, if present, return the value of the "id" key in that same dictionary?

```
{'accounts': [{'id': 'test#11882',
                         'name': 'test#11882',
                         'type': 'net',
                         'verified': False},
                        {'id': '99999',
                         'name': 'test999',
                         'type': 'web',
                         'verified': False}],
}
```

I considered indexing, however the dictionaries may be in any order and the "type : web" entry may not be present in any dictionary at all. I assume I'll need to iterate through the contents of "accounts," but I'm unsure how to verify the presence of a dict with "type : web" and then return the separate "id : x" entry in that dict.

Comment: it's just a dictionary, not a "JSON dictionary".

Comment: `for d in data['accounts']: if d.get('type') == "web": return d`? then you can just get the `'id'` from that dict? Have you tried *anything at all?*

Comment: Oh ok, "dictionary" it is.  Thank you I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `next` with a generator expression that filters your data.

```
>>> data = {
...   'accounts': [
...     {
...       'id': 'test#11882',
...       'name': 'test#11882',
...       'type': 'net',
...       'verified': False
...     },
...     {
...       'id': '99999',
...       'name': 'test999',
...       'type': 'web',
...       'verified': False
...     }
...   ],
... }
>>> next(
...   (x 
...    for x in data['accounts'] 
...    if x.get('type') == 'web'), 
...   dict()
... ).get('id')
'99999'
```

This will get the `'id'` of the first dictionary that matches. If you wanted to get all matching dictionaries a list comprehension would work nicely.

```
>>> [x for x in data['accounts'] if x.get('type') == 'web']
[{'id': '99999', 'name': 'test999', 'type': 'web', 'verified': False}]
```

Comment: This did the trick! I am unfamiliar with `next` and really appreciate your helpful answer! Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
def get_dict_id(my_dict, key):
    for d in my_dict['accounts']:
        if d['type'] =='web':
            return d['id']
    
my_dict = {'accounts': [{'id': 'test#11882',
                     'name': 'test#11882',
                     'type': 'net',
                     'verified': False},
                    {'id': '99999',
                     'name': 'test999',
                     'type': 'web',
                     'verified': False}],
}

print(get_dict_id(my_dict, 'web'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm still learning about dicts and iterating through them, and I appreciate you showing a different approach from the answer above!

Comment: Best not to use `dict` as a variable name, as it shadows the built-in type named `dict`.